# Not able to get clicked on login button, to move to next page, using phantomjs with Python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs, bootstrap-4

I am not able to get click on button using phantomjs in python selenium test cases.

here is the code that I am using in python file:

```
btn_log = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id = ('login_button')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn_log)
```

This is the login button but this is not getting clicked and nothing does change to get inside after login.

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-red btn-login" id="login_button">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

for this HTML :

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-red btn-login" id="login_button">Login</button>
```

**Python+Selenium** :

```
btn_log = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'login_button')))
btn_log.click()
```

Note that this code would work only if the **ID** is unique.

**Explanation** :

I see `<button href="#"` , **href** does not have any value, So in my opinion , even if you click, Nothing should happen.

Comment: this issue is being created by using phantomjs

Comment: I am implementing it now with headless chrome instead of using phantomjs for headless browser

Comment: what happens , when you tried with the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the desired element instead of `presence_of_element_located` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and can use either of the solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_button"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='login_button']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** :

- You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- While using `CSS_SELECTOR` or `XPATH` it is always better to construct them with the help of the `<tagName>` and minimum two attributes amongst *class*, *id*, or *others*

---

### Update

As per the HTML you have updated within the question you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-red.btn-login#login_button"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-red btn-login' and @id='login_button'][contains(.,'Login')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** :

- You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Error after using above suggested code line :              WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='login_button' and @class = 'btn-login']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\usman.ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Screenshot: available via screen

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` inconjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()                          With find_element click is not working, I mean nothing does change with this code; this happens just with using phantomjs for headless browser. With browser using chromedriver the click on login button does work and go to next page after click.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML within the question?

Comment: Pleae check it has been added in the end of question

Comment: Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: I am getting same thing like nothing happens with warning and test case failed just because of that button not being clicked: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '